# Mock a custom event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Part of a simple React component:

```
const doIt=()=>{
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('info', {detail: [1,2,3]}));
};
return (
    <button onClick={doIt}>Hello</button>
)
```

The above custom event is being listened by another component far away in the tree and invokes a callback. I want to write a test about "Hello" button without involving the listener component. How should I mock the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using jest to spy on `window.dispatchEvent`. you can do this like so:

```js
const mockDispatchEvent = jest.spyOn(window, 'dispatchEvent');
```

You can then make assertions on the mock like you would normally do with jest:

```js
expect(mockDispatchEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
```

or:

```js
expect(mockDispatchEvent).toMatchSnapshot(...);
```

Obviously this doesn't test that the event is actually emitted but you you should be able to trust that `window.dispatchEvent` does its job correctly.